# How to filter the echo response from server after an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Well, this time I'm trying to validate the type of user who's trying to log in my system. The point is I'm using AJAX to send the values from my inputs to the PHP file than validates those values. I want to get as response from that PHP file just one value that could be `id_type_user` (in case the login values was success) or "0" (if the login values were wrong) or 100 (in case there's any kind of bug with `SESSION` var), instead to get one of those 3 values. I'm getting HTML things as response from server, so I have no idea how to filter. I just do the echo which is the only thing I need.

Here is my JavaScript funcion from my `index.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#boton-entrar').click(function(e){
        if ( $('#nombreUsuario').val() != "" && $('#contrasenaUsuario').val() != "" ){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/login.ajax.php',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: 'nombreUsuario=' + $('#nombreUsuario').val().trim() + '&contrasenaUsuario=' + $('#contrasenaUsuario').val().trim(),
                    success: function(msj){
                        switch (msj) {
                            case "0":
                                    alert("Usuario o Contraseña Invalida, verifique e intente nuevamente");
                                    $(".form-horizontal").reset();
                                    break;
                            case "1":
                                    $("#wrapper").load("adminIndex.php");
                                    break;
                            case "2":
                                    $("#wrapper").load("medicoIndex.php");
                                    break;
                            case "3":
                                    $("#wrapper").load("pacienteIndex.php");
                                    break;
                            case "100":
                                    alert("Error de Session, Ya se encuentra una sesion Activa");
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    alert(msj);
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Error al intentar logear");
                    }
                });
        }else{
            alert("Debe llenar los campos para poder ingresar");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It's the code of the PHP file where I'm sending the data via AJAX (`login.ajax.php`):

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");
session_start();

// No hay sesión aún
if( !isset($_SESSION['NombreDeUsuario']) && !isset($_SESSION['CedulaDeUsuario']) ){

    //md5(md5($_POST['login_userpass'])); INVESTIGAR

    $query = "SELECT nombre_usuario,nombre,apellido,cedula,fk_tipologia_de_usuario,ultima_fecha_ingreso FROM usuarios,personas WHERE usuarios.nombre_usuario = '".$_POST['nombreUsuario']."' AND usuarios.clave_usuario = '".$_POST['contrasenaUsuario']."' AND personas.fk_usuario = usuarios.nombre_usuario ";
    $consulta = pg_query($query);

//MEJORAR
    $contador = 0;
    $resultado;
    while($row = pg_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $contador++;
        $resultado = $row;  
    }
//

    if($contador == 1){
        $_SESSION['NombreDeUsuario'] = $resultado['nombre_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['NombrePersona'] = $resultado['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['NombrePersona'] .= " ".$resultado['apellido'];
        $_SESSION['CedulaDeUsuario'] = $resultado['cedula'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario_sesion'] = $resultado['fk_tipologia_de_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['ultima_fecha_ingreso'] = $resultado['ultima_fecha_ingreso'];
        pg_query("UPDATE usuarios SET(ultima_fecha_ingreso='NOW()')");
        echo  $resultado['fk_tipologia_de_usuario'];
    }
    else{
        echo 0; 
    }           

}else{
    echo 100;
}  ?>
```

and this is the message I'm getting back from the server

```
CONEXION EXITOSA<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1'        cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: pg_query() [<a href='function.pg-query'>function.pg-query</a>]: No PostgreSQL link opened yet in C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php on line <i>12</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0174</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>374936</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\login.ajax.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0386</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>384672</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/pg_query' target='_new'>pg_query</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\login.ajax.php<b>:</b>12</td></tr>
</table></font>
 <br />
 <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
 <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span>                 Warning: pg_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>
 <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
 <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0174</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>374936</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\login.ajax.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0390</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>385040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/pg_fetch_array' target='_new'>pg_fetch_array</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\login.ajax.php<b>:</b>17</td></tr>
</table></font>
0
```

and I have now idea where that coming from, there's is a `0` at the end of all, that's the value I'm trying to catch.

Thank you before hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written:

> Warning: pg_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\GestionCitas\php\login.ajax.php on line 17

This says that the error occurs on the 17-th line and that you are not fetching data returned by *pg_query($query)* properly.

You have to check *$consulta* variable before calling the *pg_fetch_array()* function. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php). The function accepts only resource (no boolean value) as paramter 1.

Use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

If it returns 0, return 0, else fetch only the found row and process all the things with sessions.

Comment: Thank for the comment @ncq, that helped a lot, you were right I had some errors about my Postgresql link, but I already fixed that, now I'm just getting as response message "CONEXION EXITOSA1" which that "1" at the end of message means my user type, but I still cannot get inside my switch case "1" becase of the "CONEXION EXITOSA" which is before the value I need, how can I ignore that message?

Comment: I am not sure - I would guess that the "CONEXION EXITOSA" comes from included file "conexion.php". Look at this file and remove output like the mentioned message. I don't speak spanish (or what is it). It means "connected succesfully" according to google translator - so it support my hypothesis. Or you can add this string to the switch in JS, though it is quite ugly ..

Comment: Yes It's spanish, well I'm not sure where it coming from, but I modified my switch to take the last char of the incoming message and It's working finally, Thank you so much for your help mate.